# Input Onkeyup not firing in chrome and mozilla

Tags: html, asp.net-ajax

I have written an `OnKeyUp` handler for an HTML Input.  This works fine in IE8 but not in Chrome and Mozilla.

```
<input id="txtPatientSrch" runat="server" maxlength="100" onkeypress='return showPLPopup("txtPatientSrch","tblMasterPatientList");'/> 
<Script> function showPLPopup(txtCtrlName,tblName) { } </Script>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help you without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Please provide any code sample or test. Anyway, the best solution for creating cross-browser web applications is to use a library like jQuery - highly recommended!

Comment: My code is:                                                      

<input id="txtPatientSrch" runat="server" maxlength="100" onkeypress='return showPLPopup("txtPatientSrch","tblMasterPatientList");'/>     

<Script>                                                     
function showPLPopup(txtCtrlName,tblName)
{  }
</Script>